# How to count files (image) from firebase storage

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-storage

How can I count files (images) that are stored in firebase storage?
I have to use a for loop for each file that will be compared to a file that is not yet saved on firebase storage.

Answer (score 4):

There is currently no API to list or count files in Cloud Storage.  You will have to keep track of counts or files in some other database as you make changes to your storage bucket.

Answer (score 0):

You get the Number of files present in your FirebaseStorage Folder like this:

```
private int countofimages;
```

```
final StorageReference okref = mStorageRef.child("YourImagesFolder"+"/");

 okref.listAll().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<ListResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(ListResult listResult) {

        for (StorageReference item : listResult.getItems()) {
           countofimages =  listResult.getItems().size();//will give you number of files present in your firebase storage folder
                    }
          }
});
```